# Adding SSL certificate to ingress controller vs adding it to ingress resource

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Ingress controller deployment.yml

```
    spec:
  containers:
    - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=stratus/nginx-ingress-default-backend
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=ingress-controller-leader-nginx
        - --enable-ssl-passthrough
```

Ingress resource.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: 'REPOSITORY_NAME'
  namespace: service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "xyz-development.com"
    - secretName: ingress-secret-tls
  rules:
    - host: "xyz-development.com" 
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /service/
          backend:
            serviceName: 'REPOSITORY_NAME'
            servicePort: 8080
```

the secret consists of a signed certificate with the CN as xyz-development.com

endpoint : xyz-development.com/service/swagger-ui.html

If I try to access the endpoint with the above config, I end up with "Your connection is not private" error.

But if I modify the ingress controller deployment.yml to

```
    spec:
  containers:
    - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=stratus/nginx-ingress-default-backend
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=stratus/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
        - --enable-ssl-passthrough
        - --default-ssl-certificate=service/ingress-secret-tls
```

Then the site is secure with my valid certificate.

1. Is this expected behaviour?
2. Even if the default ssl certificate flag is removed in the controller, shouldn't the secret mentioned in the ingress resource.yml be used?
3. Any other pointers or better practice would be appreciated

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate? What is you CA?

Comment: @KoopaKiller its the CA of our centralised team.

Comment: OK, so the nginx container has the CA key to validate the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

There's a minor typo in your manifest that's causing the first option to fail; it should **not** be a new element in the array of `.spec.tls` entries:

```
- secretName: ingress-secret-tls # wrong
  secretName: ingress-secret-tls # correct
```

Answer (score 0):

When you getting connection is not private, are you hitting the URL https://xyz-development.com/ or using an IP address instead? If you are using an IP address, NGINX will not load that TLS certificate, it might load other default certificate (kubernetes fake certificate if you are running on k8s)

And when you add that configuration into ingress controller directly, that will become your default TLS certificate, so whatever domain name that you are using, it will give you that certificate.